# Is there a way to remove all weights from a whole ring of vertices at once?

Tags: vertex-weights

For example, when I select the ring of vertices, I see it has the weights I assigned for particular bones...[image]

But when I click on an individual vertex, I see it still has the automatic weights from when I parented it to the armature, in addition to the weights I added. Is there a way to remove all weights from a ring of vertices at once, so I can start from scratch with those particular vertices?  Seems tedious to have to select each vertex & remove weights individually.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove some vertices from all groups, go into the dropdown menu on the right of the *Vertex Groups* list and choose *Remove from All Groups*:

[image]